# Restarting CountDownTimer on finish is slower than using buttons to reset

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a timer that I want to loop as soon as it reaches 0.

Resetting the timer in onFinish() seems to be slower than manually resetting the timer via the timer's reset button.

When the timer finishes, it doesn't restart until "0" has shown for a second (maybe at the end of the tick,) effectively adding an extra second to the timer that I don't want.

How can I make this timer restart the instant "0" is displayed?

**Imports and fragment**

```
package com.example.datacollector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.Locale;

public class fragmentdro extends Fragment {
    private EditText session_edit_text;
    private EditText dro_edit_text;
    private TextView session_text_view;
    private TextView dro_text_view;
    private Button session_start_button;
    private Button dro_start_button;
    private Button session_reset_button;
    private Button dro_reset_button;
    private Button session_set_button;
    private Button dro_set_button;
    private CountDownTimer sessionTimer;
    private CountDownTimer droTimer;
    private boolean SessionTimerRunning;
    private boolean DROTimerRunning;
    private long SessionStartTimeInMillis;
    private long DROStartTimeInMillis;
    private long SessionTimeLeftInMillis = SessionStartTimeInMillis;
    private long DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROStartTimeInMillis;
    private long SessionEndTime;
    private long DROEndTime;
    View View;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dro_fragment, container, false);

        session_edit_text = View.findViewById(R.id.session_edit_text);
        dro_edit_text = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_edit_text);
        session_text_view = View.findViewById(R.id.session_text_view);
        dro_text_view = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_text_view);
        session_start_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_start_button);
        dro_start_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_start_button);
        session_reset_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_reset_button);
        dro_reset_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_reset_button);
        session_set_button = View.findViewById(R.id.session_set_button);
        dro_set_button = View.findViewById(R.id.dro_set_button);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
```

**Buttons**

```
dro_set_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                String DROinput = dro_edit_text.getText().toString();
                if (DROinput.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fill it in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                long millisInput = Long.parseLong(DROinput) * 1000;
                if (millisInput == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a positive number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                setDROTime(millisInput);
                dro_edit_text.setText("");
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        dro_start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (DROTimerRunning) {
                    pauseDROTimer();
                } else {
                    startDROTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        dro_reset_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
                if (DROTimerRunning) {
                    resetDROTimer();
                } else {
                    resetDROTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        return View;
    }
```

**Timer**

```
public void setDROTime(long milliseconds) {
        DROStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
        resetDROTimer();
    }

    public void startDROTimer() {
        DROEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + DROTimeLeftInMillis;
        final int[] secondsLeft = {0};
        droTimer = new CountDownTimer(DROTimeLeftInMillis, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long ms) {
                if (Math.round((float)ms/1000.0f) != secondsLeft[0])
                {
                    secondsLeft[0] = (int) (Math.round((float)ms)/1000.0f);
                }
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = ms;
                updateDROText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                dro_text_view.setText("0");
                DROTimerRunning = false;
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROStartTimeInMillis + 1000;
                updateDROText();
                updateDROInterface();
                startDROTimer();
            }
        }.start();

        DROTimerRunning = true;
        dro_start_button.setText("Pause");
    }

    public void pauseDROTimer() {
        droTimer.cancel();
        DROTimerRunning = false;
        dro_start_button.setText("Start");
        updateDROText();
    }

    public void resetDROTimer() {
        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            droTimer.cancel();
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = (DROStartTimeInMillis + 1000);
            updateDROInterface();
            startDROTimer();
        } else {
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = (DROStartTimeInMillis);
            updateDROText();
            updateDROInterface();
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void updateDROText() {
        int seconds = (int) (DROTimeLeftInMillis/1000)%60;

        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ":%02d", seconds));
        dro_text_view.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    public void updateDROInterface() {
        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            dro_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            dro_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            dro_edit_text.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_set_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_reset_button.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            dro_start_button.setText("Start");
        }
    }
```

**Prefs**

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putLong("SessionStartTimeInMillis", SessionStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("DROStartTimeInMillis", DROStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("MillisLeft", SessionTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putLong("DROMillisLeft", DROTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("TimerRunning", SessionTimerRunning);
        editor.putBoolean("DROTimerRunning", DROTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("EndTime", SessionEndTime);
        editor.putLong("DROEndTime", DROEndTime);

        if (sessionTimer !=null); {
            sessionTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SessionStartTimeInMillis = preferences.getLong("SessionStartTimeInMillis", 0);
        SessionTimeLeftInMillis = preferences.getLong("MillisLeft", SessionTimeLeftInMillis);
        SessionTimerRunning = preferences.getBoolean("TimerRunning", false);

        DROStartTimeInMillis = preferences.getLong("DROStartTimeInMillis", 0);
        DROTimeLeftInMillis = preferences.getLong("DROMillisLeft", DROTimeLeftInMillis);
        DROTimerRunning = preferences.getBoolean("DROTimerRunning", false);

        updateSessionText();
        updateSessionInterface();
        updateDROText();
        updateDROInterface();

        if (SessionTimerRunning) {
            SessionEndTime = preferences.getLong("EndTime", 0);
            SessionTimeLeftInMillis = SessionEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (SessionTimeLeftInMillis <0) {
                SessionTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                SessionTimerRunning = false;
            } else {
                startSessionTimer();
            }
        }

        if (DROTimerRunning) {
            DROEndTime = preferences.getLong("EndTime", 0);
            DROTimeLeftInMillis = DROEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (DROTimeLeftInMillis <0) {
                DROTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 200);
                toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 100);
                DROTimerRunning = false;
            } else {
                startDROTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra 100 ms to your DROTimeLeftInMillis

so it should look like: new CountDownTimer(DROTimeLeftInMillis + 100, 100) { ..

because the onTick method doesn't call immediately, it called a few milliseconds after, so by adding the 100 ms it should deal with the delay and give you the result you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix it. Compared to adding 1000 ms, adding 100 ms speeds up the first tick, not the final tick. For example, if the timer is set for 10 s, 10 to 9 is much quicker than 9 to 8, 8 to 7, etc.

Maybe I need to cancel and restart the timer before onFinish() is called? If not, maybe I could use a handler to schedule a countdown every 2 seconds?